# excel vba looping cells

Tags: vba, excel

I am new to vba and working on a project that can auto rearrange my spreadsheet. In one of the many steps, I loop through cells to do matching and filling. It worked but has an efficiency problem.

**SOMETHING MORE SPECIFIC **

Thank you all for replying me so quickly. I would also want to put an if statement in the loop. here is what I want to achieve ultimately:

```
sheet1 
    C1  C2  C3
R1          
R2          
R3          

sheet2
Row Col Ind
R1  C1  b
R1  C2  a
R1  C3  b
R2  C1  b
R2  C2  a
R2  C3  b
R3  C1  b
R3  C2  a
R3  C3  b
```

The code I wrote:

```
Sub test()
Dim field As Range, crit1 As Range, crit_search1 As Range, crit2 As Range, crit_search2 As Range, ind As Range
Dim i As Integer, j As Integer, m As Integer

Set field = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, j)
Set crit1 = Sheets("sheet1").Cells(i + 1, 1)
Set crit_search1 = Sheets("sheet2").Cells(m + 1, 1)
Set crit2 = Sheets("sheet1").Cells(1, j + 1)
Set crit_search2 = Sheets("sheet2").Cells(m + 1, 2)
Set ind = Sheets("sheet2").Cells(m + 1, 3)

For i = 1 To 3
    For j = 1 To 3
        For m = 1 To 9
            If crit1 = crit_search1 And crit2 = crit_search2 Then
            field = ind
    Next
Next
End Sub
```

And, the result I want to get:

```
Sheet1
    C1  C2  C3
R1  b   a   b
R2  b   a   b
R3  b   a   b
```

So basically, I am filling in a 2D matrix by matching the Row and Col criteria.

Please feel free to trash my code if there is a better solution. Thank you all!

Comment: I solved my own problem using https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/hh243933%28v=office.14%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Looping is entirely unnecessary here. You can set the value of every cell in a range, simply by saying `Range.Value = [value]` As an example:

```
Sub test()
Dim field As Range
Dim i As Integer, j As Integer

Set field = Sheets("Sheet1").Range(Cells(1,1), Cells(i, j))

field.value = "a"

End Sub
```

This will set every cell from A1 to whatever `i` and `j` correspond to, to value "a", with no looping whatsoever.

Comment: Thank you so much for your speedy response. This is just an over-simplified example. To be able to achieve what I want in my actual macro, which I am not allowed to post anything here, requires loop.

Answer (score 0):

In your posted example you're setting `field` to a fixed range - or at least it would if it didn't error out because you're trying to reference `Cells(0,0)`...

If you want to operate on an array then something like this:

```
Sub test()
    Dim arr
    Dim i As Long, j As Long

    'fill array from sheet
    arr = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(1,1).resize(100,100)

    'modify array
    For i = 1 To 100 
        For j = 1 To 100
                arr(i,j) = "R" & i & ":C" & j
        Next
    Next

    'put array back on sheet
    Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(1,1).Resize(100,100).Value = arr

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I may need more than just filling in cells. My apologies for posting such an vague example, I'd also want to achieve something like matching using an if statement, I will edit my example and re-post it.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I want, and I just found it.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/hh243933%28v=office.14%29.aspx